# Is there a cleaner and faster way to order this query in Entity Framework?

Tags: performance, linq, entity-framework

I have the following code in my application.  It works as I want it but I feel as though there has to be a cleaner way to do this without querying the database and then looping through the code to order the children.  Any thoughts on how to do this in a cleaner fashion?

```
var manufacturers = _Context.Manufacturers.Where(x=>x.IsActive).ToList();
foreach (var manufacturer in manufacturers)
{
    manufacturer.Models = manufacturer.Models.OrderBy(m => m.Name).ToList();
    foreach (var model in manufacturer.Models)
    {
        model.Sizes = model.Sizes.Where(m => m.Approved).OrderBy(m => m.SortOrder).ThenBy(m=>m.Size).ToList();
    }
}
```

where Manufacturers, Models, and Sizes are all defined entities and are children of the parent objects.

Comment: Can I ask why you're doing it this way instead of ordering the Entities as they are used?

Comment: It is being used in an MVC application, this is currently in my controller (will probably be pulled into it's own model soon) and I am using it in a view to display tables.  I would argue that the ordering logic should not be in the view layer.

Comment: I would argue that your Entity objects shouldn't be in your View layer as well. When you do copy the relevant data into a Model, sort it then.

Comment: Even if I copy this into a model by it's self I'm still left with this ugly code.

Comment: You could try a stored proc or a view to do the ordering for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using anonymous types:

```
var theThingsYouWant = _Context.Manufacturers
.Where(man => man.IsActive)
.Select(man => new
{
Manufacturer = man,
Models = man.Models.OrderBy(m => m.Name),
Sizes = man.Models.SelectMany(m => m.Sizes).Where(s => s.Approved).OrderBy(m => m.SortOrder).ThenBy( m => m.Size),
})
.ToList();
```